# Matching two sets of Data

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have one list of accounts that I pull at the beginning of the month. There is only one entry in this list per account number. I have another list which I compile throughout the month. I need for Excel to take the first list and list the entries that match to each account number. There will be a large majority that have two or more matches on the second sheet. I am currently using VLOOKUP, but it only returns the first match to each instead of listing all matches. HELLLPPPPP!!!!!!

Comment: You are pushing the limits of Excel. What you have is typical relational data that usually you'd use a database for. You might get around with some tools and tricks, but if you keep working with such data maybe have a look at MS Access or other user friendly database tools.

Answer (score -1):

Simple query in excel like the one you are using is the most excel can do, without using VBA. 
Does Excel work like a database? It can work with many limitations, but **Excel is not a database app**. If you need to use many query and you do not know how to program in VBA, I would highly recommend you to use MS Access. There are many tutorial that you can find online, that will fulfill your needs easier and more efficiently than Excel would ever do.

Comment: Glad I could help!
If you could please add my answer as an answer and an adds up would be appreciated. Best of luck.